# PowerShell not referencing array elements

Tags: arrays, powershell

I created array `$SQL_output`. If I do a `foreach` loop, it displays the contents

```
foreach ($j in $SQL_output){
    write-host $j
}
```

Output

```
118543
44021
84992
46888
```

When I add it to SQL statement

```
$SQL_UPDATE = "BEGIN
                  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM dbo.Stats
                                 WHERE Date_of_Download = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                  BEGIN
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Stats (Date_of_Download, Windows_SEP_11, Mac_SEP_11, Windows_SEP_12, Mac_SEP_12)
                      VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), $SQL_output[0],$SQL_output[1],$SQL_output[2],$SQL_output[3])
                  END
              END
"
```

The string expands to

```
BEGIN
                  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                 FROM dbo.Stats
                                 WHERE Date_of_Download = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                  BEGIN
                      INSERT INTO dbo.Stats (Date_of_Download, Windows_SEP_11, Mac_SEP_11, Windows_SEP_12, Mac_SEP_12)
                      VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 118543 44021 84992 46888[0],118543 44021 84992 46888[1],118543 44021 84992 46888[2],118543 44021 84992 46888[3])
                  END
              END
```

How to fix?

Comment: Use `$($SQL_output[0])`. Or use `-f` to format the string and use the expansions as arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing Powershell array index produces unexpected results when referenced with string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592677/referencing-powershell-array-index-produces-unexpected-results-when-referenced-w)

Comment: @EtanReisner This works, can you explain why. First time I am seeing this notation.

Comment: See the linked issue. You need to show powershell how to parse the variable (it stops early by default).

Comment: @EtanReisner ok, reading it

Comment: Another useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145704/how-can-you-use-an-objects-property-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $SQL_output[x] with $(SQL_output[x])

```
$SQL_UPDATE = "BEGIN
              IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM dbo.Stats
                             WHERE Date_of_Download = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
              BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO dbo.Stats (Date_of_Download, Windows_SEP_11, Mac_SEP_11, Windows_SEP_12, Mac_SEP_12)
                  VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), $($SQL_output[0]),$($SQL_output[1]),$($SQL_output[2]),$($SQL_output[3]))
              END
          END
"
```